# What is the purpose of DBs like CouchDB ? When they can provide beneficts over standard DB or Object like DBs With Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, architecture, couchdb

I'am Starting a new App (Something like an AngelList + hacker news but local), and got thinking if I should join the wave and get a CouchDB or stay with the old School and proved to work relational DBs, or try Object oriented DBs.

After studying a bit of how CouchDB works I don't see where It can be useful, looks harder to make connection between the "Documents" and also I cannot find how they can do BI with this Kind of DB since Data Minning would result in a lake of info in a complete mess.

I think I am missing the key points of the paradigm What am I missing ? I bet most people and Amazon are right and I am wrong, but where ?

Specially the benefits with Ruby On Rails Object Mapping ?

I would like to have some BI and cross some info after I get a lot of users... so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this post: [Cassandra vs MongoDB vs CouchDB vs Redis vs Riak vs HBase comparison](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)

Comment: Thank you gonna take a look !

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I'm going to have a look into HBase ;)